# Error when adding relationships to household

Tags: wordpress, relationships, households

We are using Civi 5.5.2 on WordPress 4.9.

When trying to add relationships to a household, we get the error in the screenshot. I am not seeing why this is happening.  Can someone tell me what I am missing?
Thank you.

[image]

****ADDED SCREENSHOT***
[image]

Comment: Are you using any Extensions such as the Permissioned Relationships one? You should be seeing checkboxes next to the two "Permission for" items

Comment: No I am not. and I don't see it on the list of available extensions.

Comment: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view/rel?cid=203&action=add&reset=1 is what you should be seeing - depending on your version of civi - but something either offering a checkbox or radio buttons to set the Permissions.

Comment: https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Frel&cid=141&action=add&reset=1 for a WP demo

Comment: Thank you. That is not what I am seeing.  Is that because I don't have the extension installed?

Comment: Thank you I found the extension for this.  Unfortunately I am getting an error 500 when I try to install it, so I will need to start another topic.

Comment: @fdarn You don't need to install any extension to make this work. The default civi behavior is to show checkboxes as you see on the demo site. I think Pete meant that there are some extensions/customization *already* enabled on your site which you need to look out for. Disable one by one and check if it fixes the relationship form or just paste the screenshot of the extension page and update the question.

Comment: You might also pull up your console see if there's a javascript error preventing those radio options from displaying/setting.

Comment: So those checkboxes are default and maybe an installed extension if conflicting with it?  I am not seeing any javacript errors in the console.  i will post a screenshot of my installed extensions.

Comment: yes it was my concern that something was interfering with civicrm and i wondered if that extension might be the problem. but you don't have it. so either something else is, or something is amiss with your core installation. iirc a change happened recently that meant the field we are talking about changed from being a checkbox to a radio button. perhaps that upgrade didn't run well on your system?